Cant exchange authorization code for an access token with Spotify Web API
I manage to get an authorization code but once i try to exchange it for an access token, i always get a 400 bad request. I'm following the authorization code with PKCE flow of Spotify's Authorization guide. I'm using React with Vite and this is my first API project
Here's my authWithPKCE.jsx:
export async function redirectToAuthCodeFlow(clientId) {
  const verifier = generateCodeVerifier(128);
  const challenge = await generateCodeChallenge(verifier);

  localStorage.setItem("verifier", verifier);

  const params = new URLSearchParams();
  params.append("client_id", clientId);
  params.append("response_type", "code");
  params.append("redirect_uri", "http://localhost:5173/home");
  params.append("scope", "user-read-private user-read-email");
  params.append("code_challenge_method", "S256");
  params.append("code_challenge", challenge);

  document.location = `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?${params.toString()}`;
}

export async function getAccessToken(clientId, code) {
  const verifier = localStorage.getItem("verifier");

  const params = new URLSearchParams();
  params.append("client_id", clientId);
  params.append("grant_type", "authorization_code");
  params.append("code", code);
  params.append("redirect_uri", "http://localhost:5173/home");
  params.append("code_verifier", verifier);

  const result = await fetch("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
    body: params,
  });
}

function generateCodeVerifier(length) {
  let text = "";
  let possible =
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
  }
  return text;
}

async function generateCodeChallenge(codeVerifier) {
  const data = new TextEncoder().encode(codeVerifier);
  const digest = await window.crypto.subtle.digest("SHA-256", data);
  return btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, [...new Uint8Array(digest)]))
    .replace(/\+/g, "-")
    .replace(/\//g, "_")
    .replace(/=+$/, "");
}

As you can see, it's pretty much the same from what they used in the tutorial for the code flow.
From my App.jsx, once the user clicks a login button it redirects to the authorization page of spotify and gets to the correct redirect uri which is my Home.jsx
Here's my Home.jsx
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { getAccessToken } from "../config/authWithPKCE";

const clientId = "";

export const Home = () => {
  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  let code = urlParams.get("code");
  console.log("Code: " + code.toString());

  const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState(null);

  const fetchAccessToken = async () => {
    const token = await getAccessToken(clientId, code);
    setAccessToken(token);
  };

  fetchAccessToken();
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Logged In</h1>
      {accessToken ? (
        <p>Access Token: {accessToken}</p>
      ) : (
        <p>Fetching access token...</p>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!
I've already tried using the two different blocks of code for the fetch token found in the tutorial and code flow but both dont seem to work still. Im honestly dumbfounded. I've also followed the tutorial on the docs and managed to make it work but cant seem to make it work on this one.

Anything in the response body?

Error response text: {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Invalid authorization code"

So it seems like i am able to get an access token but due to the nature of React's StrictMode executing components twice, the second call of the getAccessToken results in a bad request due to using the same authorization code when authorization codes are one-time uses only. I was able to find this out using the following code which displays my access token in the html itself:
<h1>
    {localStorage.getItem("access_token") ? (
      localStorage.getItem("access_token")
    ) : (
      <p>No token</p>
    )}
  </h1>

This displays my token instead of the false p tag so i was able to verify that i am, indeed getting an access token.
TLDR: React StrictMode was the culprit ( rendering components twice ).
